# relation does not exist Django Postgresql Dokku

Tags: python, django, postgresql, dokku

I created a new model on my already existing Django app.When i updated my git I did these:

```
git pull
git push dokku main
```

Then i did these:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations 
python3 manage.py migrate
```

But i get this error whenever i try to do an operation:

```
relation "accounts_articleimageshared" does not exist
```

Why??
I don't want to dump my already existing database because i would have to dump it everytime i try to update my app.How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood migrations. The steps are:

1. change your code
2. makemigrations
3. migrate
4. run your tests and check your app
5. git commit the migrations file that was just created and the rest of your code changes
6. git push